# Вывод сложения целых чисел в конслои. Java

Tags: java

Я новичок. Прошу прощения заранее, если вопрос глупый. Как вывести на экран консоли решение и результат целых чисел?
Нужно ввести число(не важно какое), например 5, затем посчитать сумму всех чисел, которые идут до 5 включительно. 1+2+3+4+5. С этим я разобрался, используя цикл for таким образом:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scNumb =new Scanner(System.in);
  int numb = scNumb.nextInt();
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i=1;i<=numb;i++){
      sum +=i;
      System.out.println(sum);
  } 
 }
}
```

Вывод на консоли:

```
1
3
6
10
15
```

Это понятно. Но как вывести само решение, чтобы вывод в консоли был:

```
1+0=1
1+2=3
3+3=6
6+4=10
10+5=15
```

?

Я пробовал использовать конкатенацию в выводе, но увы - получается какой-то бред.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= numb; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d+%d=%d%n", sum, i, sum +=i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%d + %d = ", sum, i);
sum +=i;
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(String.format("%d + %d = %d",sum, i, sum+i));